# jOOQ - add schema name to all tables

Tags: java, sql, schema, jooq

I'm using jOOQ 3.5.4 for code generation and query generation and an Azure SQL database. Is there a way to prepend the table name with the schema name in all queries (at runtime) or during the code generation process? I have only one schema currently (let's call it myschema) and some tables (let's call one of them mytable). Presently, when jOOQ creates the query it produces:

```
select * from mytable;
```

This fails to work with Azure SQL since it expects the schema name in the query like so:

```
select * from myschema.mytable;
```

Though runtime schema mapping wasn't created for this purpose, I have also tried it :

http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.5/manual/sql-building/dsl-context/runtime-schema-mapping/

by giving

```
Settings settings = new Settings()
.withRenderMapping(new RenderMapping()
.withSchemata(
    new MappedSchema().withInput("myschema")
                      .withOutput("myschema")));
```

This didn't seem to work.

I also tried adding the schema names in the xml used by the code generator, as given in

http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.5/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/

Here's what my xml looks like:

```
<database>
 .....
  <inputSchema>myschema</inputSchema>
  <outputSchema>myschema</outputSchema>

  <schemata>
    <schema>
      <inputSchema>myschema</inputSchema>
      <outputSchema>myschema</outputSchema>
    </schema>
  </schemata>
</database>
```

This didn't help either. Any suggestions?

Comment: The links to documentation above are to different versions of jOOQ; you're using 3.5 and you should try to use that documentation. Unfortunately, the example (http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.5/manual/sql-building/dsl-context/runtime-schema-mapping/) hasn't changed in 3.5. The code above should work. Odd.

Comment: I suspect this is following up on the recent [issue #4223](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/4223). Are you using the `JDBCDatabase` or the `SQLServerDatabase` to generate your code? Does the generated code reference the `myschema` schema at all?

Comment: @LukasEder Yes, this is after I got the connection to Azure SQL working with `SQLServerDatabase` to generate the code. However, in my application, I'm not really sure where I need to set this as I'm using a `org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource` bean to create a `dataSource` with `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver` as the `driverClassName`. I have, however, set the `sqlDialect` to `org.jooq.SQLDialect.SQLSERVER`. The generated code has references to `myschema` in the last private constructor in the subclasses of `org.jooq.impl.TableImpl`

Comment: Interesting, you seem to be doing everything correctly. Some more checks: 1) how do you actually construct the query with jOOQ? 2) You didn't set the `Settings.defaultSchema` value?

Comment: 1)  Here's how I'd create a query:
    `Configuration config = new DefaultConfiguration();
     config.set(new Settings().withRenderSchema(true));
     DSL.using(config).selectFrom(MYTABLE);`

2) I tried setting defaultSchema too:
    `Configuration config = new DefaultConfiguration();
     config.set(new Settings().withRenderMapping(new RenderMapping().withDefaultSchema("myschema")).withRenderSchema(true));
     DSL.using(config).selectFrom(MYTABLE);`

Still no luck

Comment: What do you get for `DSL.using(config).selectFrom(MYTABLE).getSQL(true);` ?

Comment: @AaronDigulla
`select [mytable].[mycolumn] from [mytable]`

Comment: Good. You should now be able to debug through this code and see why it's ignoring the schema when it renders the column and table name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `settings.withRenderSchema(true)`. If you have only a single schema, jOOQ optimizes that away since most databases can handle this case.

Note that the schema used in the code generator is mostly irrelevant for your case. The mapping is used to convert some odd name over which you don't have any control into something useful (like `FQ475` into `MASTER`). jOOQ puts this name into the code. You can then use `RenderMapping` to convert this internal name into the schema name which your target database uses.

If that doesn't work, set a breakpoint on `getSQL(true)` in the code below:

```
Configuration config = new DefaultConfiguration();
config.set(new Settings().withRenderSchema(true));
DSL.using(config)
.selectFrom(MYTABLE)
.getSQL(true);
```

That should allow you to see where the column/table name is rendered and why it's not what you expect.

When you found the bug, I suggest to add a minimal unit test which shows how to configure jOOQ to get it right. That way, when the problem crops up again, you can compare the actual settings to the one which you can prove works.

Comment: I found the bug in my code. I was using 2 sets of Configurations - one with renderSchema = true and the other with false and one was getting overwritten by the other when my DAO layer bean was getting created. Fixing that solved the problem. Thanks!